# Prototypal Inheritance Why Does Child Object Not Inherit Method From Parent Object?

Tags: javascript

So here is my JavaScript:

http://jsfiddle.net/GPNdM/

I have a Cat object which extends Mammal's prototype. Mammal has run() method. But when I create new Cat object and call run() it tells me it's undefined:

```
function Mammal(config) {
    this.config = config;
}
Mammal.prototype.run = function () {
    console.log(this.config["name"] + "is running!");
}

function Cat(config) {
    // call parent constructor
    Mammal.call(this, config);
}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Mammal);

var felix = new Cat({
    "name": "Felix"
});
felix.run();
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Your objects generally don't inherit from function objects. Most of the time they'll inherit from those weird little objects dangling from functions via the `.prototype` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `Cat.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype)`, that's where the methods are, not on `Mammal` directly.

http://jsfiddle.net/GPNdM/1/

Comment: Thanks. Still trying to wrap my head around this prototypal inheritance :P